# How do I pass a value from my Stream Provider to a Change Notifier Provider?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-authentication, flutter-provider

I am using 2 providers. One of them is a Stream Provider that listens to Firebase auth changes. This provider determines whether or not to show the home screen or the authenticate screen.

I want to make it so that all auth changes are also written to a variable in a different provider - a Change Notifier Provider. The reason why I want to do this is because I want to handle most other functionality using a single provider widget, but I don't know how to merge my Stream Provider and my Change Notifier Provider. So to avoid this problem, I just want to pass the current uid from the Stream Provider to the Change Notifier Provider. How do I do this? Note - I'm using the [Provider package for Flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/provider).

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<ModelAuthUser?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: ChangeNotifierProvider<GlobalsProvider>(
        create: (context) => GlobalsProvider(),
        child: Consumer<GlobalsProvider>(
          builder: (context, value, child) => const GetMaterialApp(
            title: 'MyApp',
            home: Wrapper(),
          ),
        )
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Per a comment below, this is what I originally had before when I was only using a Stream Provider (created by following a tutorial):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamProvider<ModelUser?>.value(
      value: AuthService().user,
      initialData: null,
      child: GetMaterialApp(
        title: 'MyApp',
        home: Wrapper(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating a StreamProvider in the middle of a widget build() method?

Comment: @RandalSchwartz not sure. That's just what I tried. I updated the question to show what I had before I attempted this.

Comment: Wait, are you using package:provider or package:riverpod?  That makes a difference.

Comment: @RandalSchwartz I'm using package:provider